# Android listen for connections without UUID

Tags: android, bluetooth, connect, uuid

I have written an Android game that uses Bluetooth to transfer data. I copied the code from the Bluetooth Chat application that comes with the ADK. My phone doesn't seem to be able to connect with UUID so I would like to replace it with other methods. I have already replaced my connecting methods with

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

and now I wonder how I can listen for that kind of connections? Currently there reads

```
tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,MY_UUID_SECURE);
```

but this obviously requires the UUID to be sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for Mister Smith by providing me with an answer. With a little research I was able to find an another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480480/rfcomm-connection-between-two-android-devices) with the same subject and [a good source file](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/source/browse/branches/two_dot_o/AndroidBluetoothLibrary/src/it/gerdavax/easybluetooth/LocalDevice2Impl.java?r=58) with the soluction I was looking for.

What I basically had to do is to get the BluetoothAdapter with `private BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` and then listen for connections with

```
Method m = adapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
BluetoothServerSocket tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(adapter, 1);
```